# The Content inside a Column didnt centered, i already tried MainAxisAlignment.Center

Tags: flutter, dart

The content inside the column didnt go center,i dont want to use center widget all i want is to make the widget list go center

```
class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // == size provide height and width from screen
    return Background(
          child:  Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "Welcome to my App",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: kPrimaryColor,),
              ),
              SvgPicture.asset(
                "assets/icons/chat.svg",
                height: size.height * 0.45,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                child: Text("LOGIN", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),),
                color: kPrimaryColor,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20,horizontal: 40),
              )
            ],
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Comment: use list view Instead of column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you.

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.center,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
              Text('text'),],
      )
```

Or try with a list view

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: new AppBar(),
  body: Center(
    child: new ListView(
      shrinkWrap: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
        children: [
          Center(child: new Text('your content'))
        ]
    ),
  ),
);
```

Or you can use the Align widget

```
return Scaffold(
  body: ListView( // your ListView
    children: <Widget>[
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
        child: _button("Left"),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: _button("Middle"),
      ),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
        child: _button("Right"),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: i did, nothing happen, is there anything else that i can try or fix? this is my first project. i already check every widget there is no padding or margin

Comment: try with listview